# Difference between origin and x-forwarded-host http header

Tags: http, header

At work we use several websites with several virtual hosts.

I understand what a [Virtual Host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html) is, but I don't understand the difference between the [`Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin) and [`X-forwarded-Host`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-Host) headers. (We use both of these headers at work.)

Examples from MDN:

- X-forwarded-Host=X-Forwarded-Host:  ==>`X-Forwarded-Host: id42.example-cdn.com`
- Origin==Origin:  "://"  [ ":"  ]==>`Origin: https://developer.mozilla.org`

From what I deduce from the above examples is that: `X-forwarded-Host` just contains the host and `Origin` contains the host plus the method and maybe the port.

Can someone told me if I'm wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When a request is made to a website, the user-agent (browser) will add a `Host` header to the request. The value of this header will be domain name that the request is made to. This header can be used by the server to distinguish which website you are trying to visit, for instance when the same server hosts multiple websites.

If you are using a reverse proxy, the the `Host` header will contain the value of the reverse proxy itself. In order to know to the original host, the `X-forwarded-Host` can be used. This header contains what the proxy initially received as `Host`.

Example: If you make a GET request to `https://stackoverflow.com`, the `Host` (or after the proxy `X-forwarded-Host`) header will always have the value `stackoverflow.com`.

The `Origin` header is not related to this. This header tells you from which site the request is made.
For instance, if you have a `<form>` on `example.com` that makes a POST request to `stackoverflow.com`, the `Host` will be `stackoverflow.com` (the domain the request is sent to), while the `Origin` will have the value `https://example.com`.

---

For a demonstration you can visit this link: https://jsfiddle.net/parcqhn4/

If you open the "Network" tab in your developer tools and hit the "Submit" button, you can see that the `Host` header contains the value `example.com` (which is in the `action` of the `<form>`) while the `Origin` contains the value `https://fiddle.jshell.net` (which is container that the Fiddle runs in).